# Overwrite an image that exists via PHP

Tags: php

I have created a script that allows a Manager to upload a Logo to a selected directory. I only ever want one image to exist in this directory as it's their logo for a branded section of the website. How can I make it so every time they upload an image it cleans the directory first or replaces the image that already exists?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    if (!file_exists("". $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/uploads/". $_GET['distributor'] ."/Logo/")) {
        mkdir("". $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/uploads/". $_GET['distributor'] ."/Logo/", 0777, true);
    }

    $target_dir = "". $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/uploads/". $_GET['distributor'] ."/Logo/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

        if($check !== false) {
            $uploadOk = 1;
        }

        else {
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }

    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif") {
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            header('location: ../edit-distributor.php?distributor='. $_GET['distributor'] .'&id='. $_GET['id'] .'');
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Good luck with that. You're opening your system to a **COMPLETE** remote takeover by directly using user-provided data for directory AND filename information. A malicious user can dump a file of their choosing ANYWHERE on your server. So.. sit back, relax, have a coffee. Your server will be pwn3d soon enough, making your problem moot.

Comment: @MarcB am I making my system vulnerable with the code I provided above? This is for an admin interface only accessible by staff.

Comment: @MarcB calm down. Maybe his intentions is to make a pwn3able system. So he is correct.

Comment: `$_GET['distributor'] = '../../../../../../../../../c/windows/system32'`, for one contrived example. While that uploaded file will have to have a gif/jpg extension, the fact that you allow user-data to directlly fiddle with the file system is EXTREMELY dangerous.